# php if statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any reason that my if statment below in php is not working? It does not calculate the price when the correct radio button is selected. It constantly displays price as "49"

```
     <td width="236" height="25" align="left">Booking Period:</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="10" align="right" class="align_left">One Day: ₤49 </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="radio" name="duration" id="oneday" value="One Day Rental"/>
                </td>
              </tr>

    <tr>
                <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Two Day: ₤69</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="radio" name="duration" id="two" value="Two Day Rental"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
    <tr>
                <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Weekend: ₤79</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="radio" name="duration" id="weekend" value="Weekend Rental"/>
                </td>
              </tr>

            $price = 0;
            if ($duration=="oneday")
            $price = 49;
                elseif ($duration=="two")
            $price = 69;
            elseif ($duration=="weekend")
            $price = 79;
            else
                $price = 49;

        if (empty($_POST['extras'])) {
         $price = $price;
                } else { 
                if($extra == "Deodoriser"){
                            $price = $price + 7;
                        } elseif($extra == "Carpet Protector (5 litre)"){
                            $price = $price + 39;
                        } elseif($extra == "Carpet Repair Tools"){
                            $price = $price + 9;
                        } elseif($extra == "Furniture Moving Equipment"){
                            $price = $price + 7;
                        } elseif($extra == "Furniture Tabs"){
                            $price = $price + 2;
                        } elseif($extra == "Urine Decontamination Treatment"){
                            $price = $price + 17; }
                else
        $price = $price; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way you shouldnt check the id.
You must check for the value values of the html tags.

```
        $price = 0;
        if ($duration == "One Day Rental")
          $price = 49;
        else if ($duration == "Two Day Rental")
          $price = 69;
        else if ($duration == "....")
          $price = 79;
        else
          $price = 49;
```

Thats your problem I think...

By submitting

`<input type="radio" name="duration" id="weekend" value="Weekend Rental"/>`

in the Post array duration (the name) will be with its value (value), the id does not matter here.

Comment: was waiting for the countdown! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use $_POST array as in `if (empty($_POST['extras'])) {`

`if ($_POST['duration']=="oneday") ...`

Comment: Just to add clarity to @Emmerman, you seem to have made up a variable `$duration` at least it does not seem to have been initialized in the code. It looks like you were trying to access the `'duration'` item from `$_POST`

Comment: yep, i realise now. Thanks heaps guys. I've come from knowing nothing about php and working it out in two weeks

Answer (score 2):

just modify those lines on your code

```
            $price = 0;
        $duration = $_POST['duration'];
        if ($duration=="One Day Rental")
        {   $price = 49;    }
        elseif($duration=="Two Day Rental")
        {   $price = 69;    }
        elseif ($duration=="Weekend Rental")
        {   $price = 79;    }
        else
         {   $price = 49;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `$_POST['extras']` exist and does it have values?? You should check with a `var_dump($_POST['extras'])` to see what contents are actually in there.

Otherwise, that code should work fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

- I see no `<?php ?>` is that a paste error? If so, please fix :) Otherwise you should have them around your php.
- check what `$duration` is. If that's a post variable, use it as `$_POST[]`, not just like that.
- Consider adding `{` and `}` around your ifs: it's a lot clearer what happens
- $price=$price does nothing. WHy is that there?

Comment: it is a paste error. price=price i just wanted it do do nothing if the array was empty